# Pandas to_sql() slow on one DataFrame but fast on others

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

### Goal

I'm trying to use pandas `DataFrame.to_sql()` to send a large DataFrame (>1M rows) to an MS SQL server database.

### Problem

The command is significantly slower on one particular DataFrame, taking about **130 sec** to send 10,000 rows. In contrast, a similar DataFrame takes just **7 sec** to send the same number of rows. The latter DataFrame actually has more columns, and more data as measured by `df.memory_usage(deep=True)`.

### Details

The SQLAlchemy engine is created via

`engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@<server>/<db>?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server', fast_executemany=True)`

The `to_sql()` call is as follows:
`df[i:i+chunksize].to_sql(table, conn, index=False, if_exists='replace')`
where `chunksize = 10000`.

I've attempted to locate the bottleneck via `cProfile`, but this only revealed that nearly all of the time is spent in `pyodbc.Cursor.executemany`.

Any tips for debugging would be appreciated!

Comment: If you are using `fast_executemany=True` then [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/741) may be related.

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson! This indeed appears to be the issue -- the Excel file I'm reading from had an empty cell in the first row, which resulted in passing a `None` value as described in the referenced GitHub issue. Still looking for a good solution, but may need to use an external utility like you suggested over on Github. Hopefully this bug gets fixed someday!

Comment: There's also the JSON trick described [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks-by-Database-Platform#passing-row-oriented-parameter-data-as-a-json-string). The DataFrame can be converted to a JSON string using `df.to_json(orient='records')`.

Comment: Thanks again @GordThompson! The JSON trick has solved the issue and resulted in a 30x speed increase! If you'd like to add this solution as an answer, I'll happily accept. Otherwise, I don't mind doing so. I really appreciate your help :).

Comment: Feel free to add an answer. I'm sure that others will benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Cause

The performance difference is due to an [issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/741) in `pyodbc` where passing `None` values to SQL Server `INSERT` statements when using the `fast_executemany=True` option results in slow downs.

### Solution

We can pack the values as `JSON` and use `OPENJSON` (supported on SQL Server 2016+) instead of `fast_executemany`. This solution resulted in a 30x performance improvement in my application! Here's a self-contained example, based on the documentation [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks-by-Database-Platform#passing-row-oriented-parameter-data-as-a-json-string), but adapted for  `pandas` users.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.DataFrame({'First Name': ['Homer', 'Ned'], 'Last Name': ['Simpson', 'Flanders']})
rows_as_json = df.to_json(orient='records')

server = '<server name>'
db = '<database name>'
table = '<table name>'
engine = create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://<user>:<password>@{server}/{db}')

sql = f'''
INSERT INTO {table} ([First Name], [Last Name])
SELECT [First Name], [Last Name] FROM
    OPENJSON(?)
    WITH (
        [First Name] nvarchar(50) '$."First Name"',
        [Last Name] nvarchar(50) '$."Last Name"'
    )
'''

cursor = engine.raw_connection().cursor()
cursor.execute(sql, rows_as_json)
cursor.commit()
```

### Alternative Workarounds

- Export data to CSV and use an external tool to complete the transfer (for example, the [bcp utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility)).
- Artificially replace values that are converted to `None` to a non-empty filler value, add a helper column to indicate which rows were changed, complete the operation as normal via `to_sql()`, then reset the filler values to `Null` via a separate query based on the helper column.

### Acknowledgement

Many thanks to @GordThompson for pointing me to the solution!