# Python SQLAlchemy core bulk insert slowness with fast_executemany=True and None values

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, bulkinsert

My first post here, so requesting some patience and cooperation.

- SQLAlchemy version: 1.4.39
- Database: Azure SQL Database (SQL Server)
- Python version: 3.8

I am trying to do bulk insert in this format:

***create_engine(db_conn_str, fast_executemany=True)***

***insert into table_name (?,?,?) [(),(),()]***

There are about 100 columns in the insert query. Whenever there are columns with None values, the insert performance dramatically drops. It takes about 45 seconds to insert 3000 records with None values and just 1.47 seconds by replacing the None values with empty string.

As per this article [Pandas to_sql() slow on one DataFrame but fast on others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71039589/pandas-to-sql-slow-on-one-dataframe-but-fast-on-others), it appears like a known issue with SQLAlchemy with fast_executemany=True but wondering if there is any workaround.

Comment: Your link mentions multiple "work arounds". Try one. Two years later and the issue continues to remain OPEN in github so there is no fix yet.

Comment: Are you using `to_sql()` as well?

Comment: Thanks. I don't use to_sql(). Mine is a simple insert into table_name () [()] as mentioned in my original post. 

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_insert.html

INSERT INTO user_account (name, fullname) VALUES (?, ?)
[...] (('sandy', 'Sandy Cheeks'), ('patrick', 'Patrick Star'))

Comment: Will try this: https://pypi.org/project/fast-to-sql/ and feedback when I am afree although it requires some code changes at my end to convert from dict to pandas dataframe.

Comment: pypi.org/project/fast-to-sql and pandas is a no-go as the fast-to-sql library generates 
insert query in the format 

insert into table_name values (?,?) 

instead of 

insert into table_name(col1,col2) values(?,?). 

My dataframe only contains the required columns and not everything. Looks like I need to convince my colleagues to stick with sqlalchemy and replacing None as empty string.